# Is there a way to find unresolved questions on a specific tag?

Tags: support, questions, search

Is there a way to find unresolved questions, questions that have answers but none have been accepted by the OP of question on a specific tag?

I can see the option to find ones that are 'unanswered' but not the ones that are 'unresolved'.

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "unresolved"? Wouldn't a question that has not been answered, or has not been satisfactorily answered (no answer with an accept or upvote) be unresolved? That's what that tab shows, questions with no accepted or upvoted answers.

Comment: Like this one? [search](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsupport%5D+answers%3A0).

Comment: @Kendra Updated the question.

Comment: That's much clearer. If you _just_ want questions with no accepted answers and don't care about votes, then a search on `[tag] hasaccepted:no` will do that, though the "unanswered" tab should work for that as well. (It just adds the "no upvoted answers" criteria to it) If you're seeing questions with accepted answers on that tab, it's likely caching and they haven't been removed from the list yet.

Comment: @Kendra I think that just answers the question. Mind posting one?

Comment: @M.A.R. I was working on it, Patrick beat me to it. :)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I already had one before but that didn't quite meet OP's expectations, so I already had typed half of it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search the site with a lot of custom filters that should do the trick for you.

Like this one will get all [support](/questions/tagged/support) tagged questions without an accepted answer.

```
[support] hasaccepted:no
```

You can find it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsupport%5D%20hasaccepted%3Ano).

Or [without any answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsupport%5D%20answers%3A0):

```
[support] answers:0
```